# Number of values represented by 7 digits in Binary and Hexadecimal

Tags: binary, hex

How many different values can be represented using 7 digits in Binary Systems? In Hexadecimal Systems?

Comment: how many different numbers can you represent with 3 decimal digits?  1000 right?  10 to the power 3.  4 digits 10 to the power 4.   how would that vary with different bases?

Answer (score 0):

binary 2^7 = 128 values

hexadecimal 16^7 = 268435456 values